# Magento 2 - Find out which file causes exception

Tags: magento2, layout

I get **Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'htmlClass': The attribute 'htmlClass' is not allowed.** but it does not point out which file is causing it.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'htmlClass': The attribute 'htmlClass' is not allowed.
Line: 114

Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'htmlClass': The attribute 'htmlClass' is not allowed.
Line: 131


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'htmlClass': The attribute 'htmlClass' is not allowed.
Line: 114

Element 'referenceContainer', attribute 'htmlClass': The attribute 'htmlClass' is not allowed.
Line: 131

<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:xs...', &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#000000001ef39755000000006fc4220b#, array(), NULL, '/srv/www/vhosts/...', '%message%\nLine: ...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Framewor...', array('<layout xmlns:xs...', &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#000000001ef39755000000006fc4220b#, array(), NULL, '/srv/www/vhosts/...', '%message%\nLine: ...')) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:66]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewor...', array('xml' => '<layout xmlns:xs...', 'schemaFile' => '/srv/www/vhosts/...', 'validationState' => &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#000000001ef39755000000006fc4220b#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\Framewor...', array('xml' => '<layout xmlns:xs...', 'schemaFile' => '/srv/www/vhosts/...', 'validationState' => &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#000000001ef39755000000006fc4220b#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php:43]
#5 Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(array('xml' => '<layout xmlns:xs...', 'schemaFile' => '/srv/www/vhosts/...', 'validationState' => &Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState#000000001ef39755000000006fc4220b#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php:141]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('<layout xmlns:xs...', 'layout_merged', false) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:494]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_adminhtml...', '<body>\n   <refer...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:470]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load(array()) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge/Interceptor.php:193]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge\Interceptor->load() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:86]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:63]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:212]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config.php:225]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config->publicBuild() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:242]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000001ef39685000000006fc4220b#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000001ef39685000000006fc4220b#) called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:193]
#16 Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(&Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor#000000001ef39685000000006fc4220b#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:141]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#18 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#19 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000001ef39682000000006fc4220b#) called at [index.php:42]
</pre>
```

Comment: the error occurs in xml layout file. can you please search in all xml files of the entire project for the string "htmlClass"?

Comment: @MosheShperling, are you serious? There are hundres of files. I think there is a merged layout file somewhere where I can search.

Comment: i tried it before commenting. not in every file this string appears. in my magento i got only 6 rows as results